# Java Stack Cannot invoke push(E) on the array type E[]

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I have a probelm. I know that i have to allocate a new stack of a double size, if my stack is full. I have tryed to use a temp Stack, but during the compilation, I have see an error on a 55 line. The error is "Cannot invoke push(E) on the array type E[]". I have no idea why i can't do this metod.

```
package stack;

import exception.EmptyStackException;

import exception.FullStackException;

public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E>{

protected int capacity;
protected static final int CAPACITY = 1000;
protected E S[];
protected int top = -1;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayStack(int capacity){
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.S = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity];
}

public ArrayStack(){
    this(CAPACITY);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return top+1;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpety() {
    return (this.top < 0);
}

@Override
public E top() throws EmptyStackException {
    if(isEmpety())
        throw new EmptyStackException("Stack Vuoto.");
    return this.S[top];
}

@Override
public void push(E element) throws FullStackException, EmptyStackException {
    if(size() == capacity){
        this.tempStack();

    }
    //throw new FullStackException("Stack Pieno.");
    this.S[++top] = element;
}

private void tempStack(){
    E tempS[] = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity];
    E tempEl;
    while(isEmpety()){
        tempEl = this.pop();
        tempS.push(this.pop());
    }
    this.capacity += this.capacity;
    this.S = null;
    this.S = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity];
}

public void union(Stack<E> s){

}

@Override
public E pop() throws EmptyStackException {
    E element;
    if(isEmpety())
        throw new EmptyStackException("Stack Vuoto.");
    element = S[top];
    this.S[top--] = null;
    return element;
}

}
```

Comment: We also have no idea, why are you trying invoke  nonexistent method `push` on `array` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tempS` is not a `Stack`, so you can't call methods of `Stack` for this variable.

What your `tempStack` method should do is probably create an array of a larger capacity, copy `this.S` to the new array and assign that array to `this.S`.

Comment: if(size() == capacity){
   this.capacity += this.capacity;
   E tempS[] = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity];
   tempS = this.S;
   this.S = null;
   this.S = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity];
   this.S = tempS;   
  } when i copy this.S in tempStack the size remains the old size

Comment: @MarcoFerraioli `tempS = this.S` does not copy this.S to tempS, it just copies the reference. You should use Arrays.copyOf to copy the elements of the original array to a target array.

Answer (score 0):

```
E tempS[] = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity];
```

tempS is an array not a **Stack** so you can't call push method on it